# How to know that AG GRID purge process is still in progress?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I have a use case where numerous background processes are running on the ag-grid row nodes, involving filters and other operations.

When I apply a specific filter, such as a time range, I need to purge the grid and retrieve new records. However, during the grid purging process, the continuous background processes are unable to locate the nodes and encounter errors. Hence, I am seeking a way to determine when the server-side row model grid completes the purging operation.

For reference, I am using the following call:

`gridApi.refreshServerSideStore({ purge: true })`

I have checked whether refreshServerSideStore returns a promise, but it seems that it does not. I would appreciate any suggestions or ideas on how to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is an event for this [storeRefreshed](https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-serverSideRowModel-storeRefreshed)